# Why does Cauchy condensation test requires positiveness?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I looked several versions, I have found two versions of it.

Let $a_n$ be a monotonic decreasing positive sequence, then $\sum a_n$ converges iff $\sum 2^n a_{2^n}$

2nd version:

Let $a_n$ be a monotonic sequence that converges to zero, then $\sum a_n$ converges iff $\sum 2^n a_{2^n}$

Now it states that the sequence must be monotonic decreasing and positive, why isn't monotonicity enough? Since if the sequence is negative (and monotonic), we can multiply by -1 and get a positive sequence (and also monotonic), and if that sequence converges then the original one must converge as well.

So why is the positiveness required? The proof works the same if we multiple everything by -1.
In the 2nd version, the positiveness is replaced by convergences to zero, however if the sequence does not converge to zero (and is monotonic) then $a_{2^n}$ is also monotonic and does not converge to zero.

So the question is, can we require just monotonicity for the test to work? In one version, positiveness is required, in another, convergence to zero is required, are the two extra requirement unnecessary?

Comment: “The proof works the same if we multiple everything by -1.” So why bother the negative version?

Comment: The question is legitimate, but trivial: positive series are equivalent to negative series. Troubles begin when series of constant sign are replaced by series of terms with variable sign.

Comment: @Jack then why require the positiveness at all? Why constrain yourself?

Comment: @Siminore Yes I can see why this is troublesome, but wouldn't monotonicness solve this for you? Since if you switched from positive to negative then you have a sequence that doesn't converge to zero, hence nonconvergance?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Please give the complete *statement* that you think is correct.

Comment: You said you have found *two* versions. What is the other?

Comment: One reason is that positiveness ensures that $a_n$ can converge to zero. For instance $b_n=-1-\frac{1}{n}$ is decreasing and, since $b_n\to-1$, clearly $\sum b_n$ does not converge.

Comment: Updated the post with the 2nd version and a more clear question

Comment: Monotonicity of $a_n$ for all sufficiently large $n$ is necessary for this test to be applicable. For example if  $a_n=0$ when n is a power of $2$ and $a_n=1$   when $n$ is not a power of $2$ , the test is invalid.

Comment: All of the content in the theorem is embodied in the nonnegative case. The non positive case is a trivial corollary. Why muddy up the statement with more verbiage in such a situation?

Answer (score 2):

If $(a_n)$ is monotonic and converges to zero, one of the following two cases must be true:

- $a_n\geq 0$ for all $n$ and $a_n$ is decreasing;
- $a_n\leq 0$ for all $n$ and $a_n$ is increasing.

In the second case, let $b_n:=-a_n$. Then one has the first case again. Also, in the second case, $\sum_n a_n$ converges iff $\sum_n b_n$ converges; moreover, $\sum 2^na_{2^n}$ converges iff $\sum 2^nb_{2^n}$ converges. Thus [without loss of generality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Without_loss_of_generality), one can focus on the nonnegative case *only*.

Comment: And if $a_n \to L \ne 0$ then $2^n a_{2^n} \to ±\infty$, both diverge, so is the convergence to zero is a requirement? Or is it also unnecessary? (Like, does the theorem works only if the only constrain we put on $a_n$ is to be monotonic?

Comment: Are you asking that whether $a_n$ being monotone only can imply that "$\sum a_n$ converges iff $\sum 2^na_{2^n}$ converges"?

Comment: That would not be an interesting statement in the first place, since if $a_n\to 0$ is *not* true (say $a_n\to L\neq 0$), then $\sum a_n$ will never converge. After all, we are talking about "convergence" test.

Comment: Yes, that's my question all along, although I suck in explaining.

Comment: Then that case is trivial: if $a_n$ does not converge to $0$, then both $\sum a_n$ and $\sum 2^na_{2^n}$ diverges and there is nothing to prove.

Comment: Yes, but in all versions, it either says that $a_n$ is monotonic, and either converges to zero or with positive terms.      They always added an extra condition, why?